# android app update causing deleted app shortcuts and error message

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

My Android app was updated on the Marketplace (Google Play, whatever) yesterday and some of my users reported that after the update they were getting the message "the linked program is no longer installed on your phone" when they tried opening their app.  I did a little research on this message and it seems like it's more common to situations where the app is installed on the sdcard.  That is not the case in my situation.

I did a simulated update via adb install -r and sure enough I found that this particular update was causing issues I hadn't seen before on my phone (in my case I saw that the shortcut to the app on the Home screen had been deleted, when usually that's not the case after updates).

The main difference in this update is that between my last version and this version I updated my Eclipse to a newer version, as well as refactored a file/class or two in my project.  I also added a workaround for Android/Google bug #2373 where I do a quick restart of the app the first time it gets opened.

One more possibly helpful tidbit:  I built a new install this morning for testing and the only difference between it and the latest version on the Marketplace is that I bumped up the version number.  This appears to update fine (without causing issues with the app shortcut disappearing) after a simulated update with adb install -r.

Any ideas why I'm seeing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you've done some refactoring. If you have changed the name (or the package name) of your root activity (the one that has action.MAIN and category.LAUNCHER in the manifest) then the shortcut on the homescreen won't be able to find your activity to launch it.

Comment: Ooh, I think that's it!  The Android/Google bug #2373 originally necessitated that I change my MAIN/LAUNCHER activities to a "dummy".  That dang bug has cost me more time in the past month...